# Is it possible to apply Master Theorem for finding the square and cube root

Tags: algorithms, recursion

I was asked to calculate the running time of an algorithm which finds the square root and cube root of a given number.

Is it possible to apply [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) with regards to this? First, I need to build the recursive relation to it.

**Recursive algorithm :** (for square root)

The cube root  is also similar  with slightest modification

```
float sqrt_recursion(float n, float low, float high) {
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (Math.abs(mid*mid-n)<0=0.00001) {
        return mid;
    } else {
        if ((mid * mid) > n)
            return  sqrt_recursion(n, low, mid - 1);
        else
            return  sqrt_recursion(n, mid + 1, high);
    }
}
```

**Recursive algorithm :** (for cube root)

```
float cbrt_recursion(float n, float low, float high) {
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (Math.abs(mid*mid*mid-n)<0=0.00001) {
        return mid;
    } else {
        if ((mid * mid *mid) > n)
            return  cbrt_recursion(n, low, mid - 1);
        else
            return  cbrt_recursion(n, mid + 1, high);
    }
}
```

Above code uses the [Newton-Raphson method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to calculate the square root.

**My Analysis :**

I could not exactly determine in which order the loop is executed. It is not exactly as O(log n) , because the mid value is not always reducing rather it moves up and down.

Accodring to me , it do not converge to result as qucikly as binary search does.

*Is above analysis correct ?*

Please help me in finding the exact running time

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Please find updated question

Comment: the problem is about _cube_ root - it's [unclear](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6489#6489) what does code for _square_ root do with it

Comment: @gnat ..sorry for that ..i need find for both actually..updated the question..it uses the newton raphson method for calculating the square root. I tested it and its giving appropriate value. I need to figure out how to find number of iterations it is taking to do this in general?

Comment: It is some what similar to how a binary search works..but still i feel there is significant differnce..

Comment: Ok, now this question is answerable :) I'll be glad to help, but could you first explain what you've tried to solve the problem yourself? You correctly note that you need to transform the function into a recursive function – maybe try to do that and [edit] the question to show your results. Hint: you need another function with the signature `float recursive(float n, float low, float high)` for this.

Comment: sure..i will edit the question with recursive approach..and get back to you..thanks

Comment: @amon..i converted the iterative algorithm into recursive. How to build the recurrance relation from it? can you please in this so that i can continue with applying the masters theorm to solve it.

Comment: @amon..please find above analysis

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Master theorem, but have you tried letting n be (high-low)*epsilon (where epsilon is 0.00001 in the above example)? Then I think b=2, a=1, and f(n)=1. Does that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current recursive code is slightly incorrect, because the type of `mid` is `int` and not `float`. Once corrected, a recursive version of the iterative algorithm is:

```java
final static float EPSILON = 0.00001;

static float sqrt(float n) {
    // Here, I use high = n for simplicity's sake.
    // In a real application, I'd special-case n = 0, …, 4
    // and start with high = n/2
    return recursiveSqrt(n, 0, n);
}

static float recursiveSqrt(float n, float low, float high) {
    float mid = (low + high) / 2;
    float midSquare = mid * mid;

    // This is the base case of the recursion
    // which corresponds to a loop condition.
    if (math.abs(midSquare - n) < EPSILON) return mid;

    // Anything that's not the base case recurses.
    // Here, we recurse either into the left or right half
    // of the currently processed interval
    if (midSquare > n) return recursiveSqrt(n, low, mid);
    else               return recursiveSqrt(n, mid, high);
}
```

Now, the Master Theorem is interested not in the specific implementation of the recursive function, but in three properties:

1. What is the running time at each step, excluding the recursion?
2. How often do we recurse per invocation?
3. How does the problem size shrink with each invocation?

Together, these define the parameters *f(n)*, *a*, and *b* in the Master-Theorem equation

> `T(n) = a · T(n/b) + f(n)`

that describes the complexity of some recursive functions. Note that the `f(n)` function is also a complexity expression. It describes the per-iteration overhead, which may depend on the problem size in each iteration.

The answer to the first question is that each invocation has constant running time (recursion excluded), because arithmetic operators, comparison operators, and `Math.abs()` take constant time. The only way to have non-constant time is to use loops or to invoke a function or method that has non-constant time – and we don't do any of that. Therefore, `f(n) = O(1)`.

Next, we have to determine how often we recurse. While the code contains two invocations of the recursive function, only one of them will be executed in any iteration. So `a = 1`.

Finally, we have to look at the problem size. The problem size of each iteration is *not* our parameter `n`. Instead, it is the range `high - low`. At each iteration, you *halve* this range by calculating the midpoint. Therefore, `b = 2`. It doesn't matter where this range is and whether an iteration picks the lower or upper half. Only the size of the range matters. The initial size of the range is `n`.

Now we have determined all parameters necessary to apply the Master Theorem.

Our parameters do not match the first case where `f(n) = O(nc)` for some parameter `c` with `c < logb(a)`: Here we have `c = logb(a) = 0`.

However, it immediately matches the second case where `f(n) = Θ(nc · logk(a))` with `k ≥ 0` and `c = logb(a)` (The character `Θ` that looks like a zero is actually the Greek letter uppercase Theta). Here, `c = k = 0`.

Then, the total complexity is `T(n) = Θ(nc · logk + 1(n)) = Θ(log n)`.

**Interpretation:** This method for approximating a square root is essentially a binary search over the ordered sequence of all numbers between zero and `n`. This sequence is discrete, and all numbers in the sequence are `2·epsilon` apart. At each iteration, we have lower and upper bounds delimiting a sublist which must contain the wanted list item. Because the sequence is ordered, we look at the item in the middle of the sub-sequence and then continue searching in the left or right sublist, depending on whether the middle item was larger or smaller than the wanted item. Consequently, this algorithm must have the same time complexity characteristics as a binary search.

Comment: Wow..I have unlearned the way i have learned Masters theorm and relearnt the amazing way you have shown in the above answer. Really appreciate your time into this.Thank you very much. +1 for its completeness

Comment: Really great answer, and best answer to solve square root I've found.